# CSS text-overflow property

Tags: html, css

I want to show the text an ellipsis to the user.
I use the text-overflow property.
Text must be next to numbers, but text is long.
If I define the width, there is a large space, which is ugly. If I put the  width auto, the text is long
This is code:

```css
.holder-new {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 90%;
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.holder-content {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.name {
  padding: 0!important;
  width: auto!important;
  padding-right: 5px!important;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
}

.duration {
  padding: 0!important;
  width: 15%!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder-new">
  <div class="holder-content">
    <div class="name"><span>The text-overflow property </span></div>
    <div class="duration"><span>1:02</span></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="holder-new">
  <div class="holder-content">
    <div class="name"><span>The text-overflow property specifies how overflowed content that is not displayed should be signaled to the user </span></div>
    <div class="duration"><span>1:02</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/689404/

Comment: I think you may need to set the width to 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set a fixed px or percentage width for the right DIV (the time) and set `width: auto` for the left DIV (i.e. the text). If you use a pixel value for the right DIV, it will work for all container sizes / be responsive:

https://jsfiddle.net/em2svpko/